# How can I go from a SVG file to a Polygon string with ID table in Python?

Tags: python, polygon, coordinates, svg, xy

I would like to translate my SVG file (objects) into polygons. The result I would like to obtain is a table with a column of IDs and another column with the Polygons in it (string). I would like to use Python for it. Is there any possibility? Maybe from SVG to xy coordinates and then to Polygons?

Comment: A quick web search turned up this Python library for reading SVG geometries (https://pypi.org/project/svgpathtools/).  Combine that with  pyshape for a GIS output (https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/)